# A question about the changes of $f$ when an inequality between $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ is satisfied

Tags: functions, derivatives, inequality, functional-inequalities

I have two independent, continuous functions that satisfy the following inequality
$$f(x,y) \ge g(x,y).$$
Now suppose $g(x,y)$ is set to be fixed, then $x$ and $y$ are constrained. Both functions are positive definite and their domains only take positive values.

My question: Is there any way to find an inequality (or any relation) between $\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right|_y$ and $\left. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right|_g$ ?

Or, is it possible to have an estimate of the changes of $f$, I mean $\Delta f = f(x_2,y_2)-f(x_1,y_1)$, when $g$ is kept fixed?

Comment: What do you mean with "$g(x,y)$is set to be fixed, then $x$ and $y$ are constrained"?: like $g(x,y)\equiv g(x_0,\ y_0)$ at some fixed point $(x_0,\ y_0)$? If that is the case you require to $f(x,y)> \text{constant value}$ so probably it will only possible if  $\text{constant value} \equiv \sup\|g\|$, right?

Comment: @Joako - Thanks for your attention. I meant $g(x,y)= constant$ for any set of $(x , y)$ for some physical reasons in my problem, which means that $x$ and $y$ are no longer independent variables.

Comment: What is $\partial f/\partial x|y$ and $\partial f/\partial x|g$ ? And what does it mean that $f$ is positive definite ? $f > 0$ for all $(x,y)$ ?

Comment: i think the setting is problematic, a functions is positive definite if and only if it it is the Fourier transform of some non-negative measure, if g(x,y) is a constant function, then it can not be positive definite, since its Fourier transform will simply be the Dirac distribution at the origin and scaled by the same constant

Comment: @Cactus - It means during the derivative $\partial f/\partial x|y$, $y$is held fixed.  And $f$ always takes positive values for any sets of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @sb945 - Yes, I asked my question in a bad way. Correction is needed. Thanks for your comment.